# Why does an implication arrow have a boolean value?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Looking at truth tables, I understand if there is a column something like:

$p\\
0\\
1$

However, I do not understand something such as

$p \to q \\ 1 \\1$

Why does an if-then statement itself have a boolean value?

Thanks

Comment: It's because intuitively, 'if ... then ...' statements have a truth-value. If I say: "If $x$ is even, then $x$ is divisible by $2$', then you would consider that to be a true statement, but "If $x$ is even, then $x$ is divisible by $3$' you would say is false.

Comment: An implication P --> Q  is a proposition ( provided P and Q are propositions). A proposition has a truth value ( that depends on the truth values of its components).

Comment: Ah, I see, I suppose I was mixed up with the double line arrow rather than the single line arrow.